# Formula for $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a^{|j-k|}/j$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I'm looking at finding a formula (or an approximation) for the following sum:

$$ S_{k} = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{a^{|j-k|}}{j}$$
where it is known that $|a|<1$. This series seems to converge, but I'm not sure how to handle the power shift of $|j-k|$.

Are there known results for similar formulas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{array}\\
S_{k} 
&= \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{a^{|j-k|}}{j}\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \dfrac{a^{|j-k|}}{j}+\sum_{j=k+1}^{\infty} \dfrac{a^{|j-k|}}{j}\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \dfrac{a^{k-j}}{j}+\sum_{j=k+1}^{\infty} \dfrac{a^{j-k}}{j}\\
&= a^k\sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \dfrac{a^{-j}}{j}+a^{-k}\sum_{j=k+1}^{\infty} \dfrac{a^{j}}{j}\\
&= a^k\sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \dfrac{a^{-j}}{j}+a^{-k}\sum_{j=k+1}^{\infty} \dfrac{a^{j}}{j}\\
\end{array}
$

These are both partial sums
of
$-\ln(1-z)
=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{z^j}{j}
$.
Wolfy uses the
Hurwitz Lerch transcendent.